# App crashing in swift on array

Tags: swift

I have a list of image file names, and every time the app tries to run it crashes on the line which declares the array of image names.

```
class Home: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var banner: UIImageView!

var imageList:[String] = ["image1", "image2", "image3", "image4"]
let maxImages = 3
var imageIndex: NSInteger = 0
```

Comment: I have no error, is says Thread 1: breakpoint 3.5 for the line declaring the array

Comment: Look at the line numbers gutter in Xcode, to the left of the highlighted line. If there's a blue rectangle, remove it: it's a breakpoint. You may have set one accidentally.

Comment: Yea that fixed it, stupid mistake on my part. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error "Thread 1: breakpoint 2.1"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32038226/error-thread-1-breakpoint-2-1)