# Breakpoint Kingfisher

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I am working with a simple framework called Kingfisher to download pictures and cache them, but I get a breakpoint when I run the app.. I can't seem to figure out why this is happening!

```
import Kingfisher
    let URL = NSURL(string: "http://graph.facebook.com/100003866283798/picture?type=normal")
    imageView.kf_setImageWithURL(URL!)
```

Any help is really appreciated!
Thanks

this is what I get in the console: `self    Facebook_Detective.TestView 0x00007fa0fb426fc0  0x00007fa0fb426fc0
UIKit.UIViewController  UIViewController

imageView   UIImageView!    0x00007fa0fb671780  0x00007fa0fb671780
UIView  UIView

_storage    id  0x0 0x0000000000000000
_lastResolvedTraitCollection    id  0x0 0x0000000000000000
_templateSettingsAreInvalid bool    false   false
_edgeInsetsForEffectsAreValid   bool    false   false
__animatesContents  bool    false   false
URL NSURL?  0x3ff0000000000000  0x3ff0000000000000
ObjectiveC.NSObject NSObject`

Comment: A breakpoint or an error?

Comment: I can build the app, but after the lauchscreen the app crashes because of a breakpoint

Comment: Then have a look at my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32038226/error-thread-1-breakpoint-2-1).

Comment: Doesn't help.. The app doesn't crashes anymore but it still doesn't work

Comment: You had two problems, now one of them is resolved. I wouldn't call that "doesn't help". ;)

Comment: Breakpoints don't crash apps.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't drag them out all now it's working thanks man! Really appreciate that!