# Swift 2 Crash optionals

Tags: swift2, xcode7

I have updated my app to Xcode 7 and converted to swift2 I have cleared all the errors but now when running the app it crashes just after seeing the launch screen. from below code this line is highlighted in green (thread 1 : breakpoint 1.4):

```
var cellNumber:Int! = 1
```

I really don't know what is causing an issue. Its my first app please please excuse me for odd ways of coding:

ViewOne.swift

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

        class ViewOne : UITableViewController {



        override internal func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

        }

        var cellNumber:Int! = 1
        //var cellNumber = 1

        @IBAction func Cell2Pressed(sender: UIButton) {
            cellNumber = 2
            }

        @IBAction func Cell3Pressed(sender: UIButton) {
            cellNumber = 3
        }


        @IBAction func Cell4Pressed(sender: UIButton) {
            cellNumber = 4
        }

        @IBAction func Cell5Pressed(sender: UIButton) {
            cellNumber = 5
        }

        @IBAction func Cell6Pressed(sender: UIButton) {
            cellNumber = 6
        }

        @IBAction func Cell7Pressed(sender: UIButton) {
            cellNumber = 7
        }

        @IBAction func Cell8Pressed(sender: UIButton) {
            cellNumber = 8
        }

        @IBAction func Cell9Pressed(sender: UIButton) {
            cellNumber = 9
        }



        override internal func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        }

    `//  @IBOutlet weak var Cell1Pressed: UITableViewCell!` 


        override internal func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
            let DestViewControler : ViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewController
           // var Dest2ViewControler : RadioPlayer = segue.destinationViewController as! RadioPlayer

           DestViewControler.trackNumber = cellNumber!
           // Dest2ViewControler.trackNumber = cellNumber




        }


    }
```

ViewControler.swift

```
    `import UIKit`
`import AVFoundation`
`import MediaPlayer`

`class ViewController: UIViewController {`


    override func canBecomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    static let sharedInstance = ViewController()
    @IBOutlet var PausePlay: UIButton!

    var ButtonAudioPlayer = try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("ButtonAudio", ofType: "wav")!))

    private var BackgroundAudio1 = try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Ants", ofType: "mp3")!))
    private var BackgroundAudio2 = try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Ants", ofType: "mp3")!))
    private var BackgroundAudio3 = try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Ants", ofType: "mp3")!))
    private var BackgroundAudio4 = try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Ants", ofType: "mp3")!))
    private var BackgroundAudio5 = try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Ants", ofType: "mp3")!))
    private var BackgroundAudio6 = try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Ants", ofType: "mp3")!))
    private var BackgroundAudio7 = try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Ants", ofType: "mp3")!))
    private var BackgroundAudio8 = try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Ants", ofType: "mp3")!))
    private var BackgroundAudio9 = try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Ants", ofType: "mp3")!))




    var trackNumber = Int()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

       play()





        //in info.playlist you need to add 'Required background modes and add to idem 0 ap plays audio airplay then below code to play even when iphone is locked: -marcin
        /*
        PausePlay.setTitle("Play", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
        } catch _ {
        }

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        PausePlay.setTitle("Play", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        if NSClassFromString("MPNowPlayingInfoCenter") != nil {
            let image:UIImage = UIImage(named: "logo_player_background")!
            let albumArt = MPMediaItemArtwork(image: image)
            let songInfo: NSMutableDictionary = [
                MPMediaItemPropertyTitle: "WIND",
                MPMediaItemPropertyArtist: "DEEP BASE",
                MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork: albumArt
            ]
            MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.defaultCenter().nowPlayingInfo = songInfo as [NSObject : AnyObject]
            //MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.defaultCenter().nowPlayingInfo = songInfo
        }
        if (AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)) {
            print("Receiving remote control events")
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
        } else {
            print("Audio Session error.")
        }

*/

}
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func PlayAudio1(sender: AnyObject) {
        ButtonAudioPlayer!.play()

    }
    @IBAction func Stop(sender: AnyObject) {

        stop()

        //BackgroundAudio1.stop()
        //BackgroundAudio1.currentTime = 0

        //PausePlay.setTitle("Play", forState: UIControlState.Normal)





    }

    @IBAction func Restart(sender: AnyObject) {

        BackgroundAudio1!.stop()
        BackgroundAudio1!.currentTime = 0
        BackgroundAudio1!.play()


    }


    @IBAction func PausePlay(sender: AnyObject) {

        /*
        if (BackgroundAudio.playing == true){
            BackgroundAudio.stop()
            PausePlay.setTitle("Play", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

        }
        else{

            BackgroundAudio.play()
            PausePlay.setTitle("Pause", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            }
            */



        toggle()



    }


    private var isPlaying = false


    func play() {

        if(trackNumber == 2){
            BackgroundAudio2!.play()}
        if(trackNumber == 3){
            BackgroundAudio3!.play()}
        if(trackNumber == 4){
            BackgroundAudio4!.play()}
        if(trackNumber == 5){
            BackgroundAudio5!.play()}
        if(trackNumber == 6){
            BackgroundAudio6!.play()}
        if(trackNumber == 7){
            BackgroundAudio7!.play()}
        if(trackNumber == 8){
            BackgroundAudio8!.play()}
        if(trackNumber == 9){
            BackgroundAudio9!.play()}

        isPlaying = true
    }

    func pause() {
        if(trackNumber == 2){
            BackgroundAudio2!.pause()}
        if(trackNumber == 3){
            BackgroundAudio3!.pause()}
        if(trackNumber == 4){
            BackgroundAudio4!.pause()}
        if(trackNumber == 5){
            BackgroundAudio5!.pause()}
        if(trackNumber == 6){
            BackgroundAudio6!.pause()}
        if(trackNumber == 7){
            BackgroundAudio7!.pause()}
        if(trackNumber == 8){
            BackgroundAudio8!.pause()}
        if(trackNumber == 9){
            BackgroundAudio9!.pause()}

        isPlaying = false
    }

    func pause2() {

            BackgroundAudio2!.pause()

            BackgroundAudio3!.pause()

            BackgroundAudio4!.pause()

            BackgroundAudio5!.pause()

            BackgroundAudio6!.pause()

            BackgroundAudio7!.pause()

            BackgroundAudio8!.pause()

            BackgroundAudio9!.pause()

        isPlaying = false
    }


    //dodana przezemnie:
    func stop() {
        if(trackNumber == 2){
            BackgroundAudio2!.stop()}
        if(trackNumber == 3){
            BackgroundAudio3!.stop()}
        if(trackNumber == 4){
            BackgroundAudio4!.stop()}
        if(trackNumber == 5){
            BackgroundAudio5!.stop()}
        if(trackNumber == 6){
            BackgroundAudio6!.stop()}
        if(trackNumber == 7){
            BackgroundAudio7!.stop()}
        if(trackNumber == 8){
            BackgroundAudio8!.stop()}
        if(trackNumber == 9){
            BackgroundAudio9!.stop()}

        isPlaying = false
    }

    func toggle() {
        if isPlaying == true {
            pause()
        } else {
            play()
        }
    }

    func currentlyPlaying() -> Bool {
        return isPlaying
    }

    override func remoteControlReceivedWithEvent(event: UIEvent?) {
        if event!.type == UIEventType.RemoteControl {
            if event!.subtype == UIEventSubtype.RemoteControlPlay {
                print("received remote play")
                play() // these are producing terrible error
            } else if event!.subtype == UIEventSubtype.RemoteControlPause {
                print("received remote pause")
                pause2() // these are producing terrible error
            } else if event!.subtype == UIEventSubtype.RemoteControlTogglePlayPause {
                print("received toggle")
                ViewController.sharedInstance.toggle()
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error "Thread 1: breakpoint 2.1"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32038226/error-thread-1-breakpoint-2-1)

Answer (score 0):

Right off the bat, I think you should say:

```
var cellNumber: Int? = 1
```

The expression `Int!` unwraps an optional variable, but you would use `Int?` to declare an optional variable.