# New to swift, my program will crash pressing open

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I press open on the simulator and the program crashes and gives me that side panel and bottom pressing open is sliding to the right and displaying the 3 objects Hello, second, World.

[image]

Comment: the number one is the image file.

Comment: You don't have enough reputation to share image instead of that you can use http://imgur.com/ and share link or show your code.

Comment: It is not a crash. It stopped on a breakpoint. See [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-source_editor/chapters/Creating,Disabling,andDeletingBreakpoints.html) documentation.

Comment: it's a breakPoint. Your app is not crash. just debug.

Comment: you meant viewDidLoad() ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error "Thread 1: breakpoint 2.1"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32038226/error-thread-1-breakpoint-2-1)

Answer (score 1):

Your program is crashing because you have added break point into you code which is looks like:

[image]

You can remove all by dragging it out side this way:

[image]

Do same thing for all breakpoints.

Comment: I have one doubt , how do you create the GIF type output from simulator

Comment: I am not getting you.

Comment: always you show the output in some action format , correct , how do u created this type of output insimulator

Answer (score 0):

Your program is not crashing . It was stopped at the breakpoint you have used in your code.