# Thread 1: breakpoint 7.3 Xcode 7 swift

Tags: xcode, swift, multithreading

After I open a certain page of my app, it crashes on the simulator, and shows an error "Thread 1: breakpoint 7.3" in Xcode. When I open this page, it won't even call the viewDidLoad() method... My best guess is that the problem arises from the storyboard because I was trying to implement a search bar before I screwed things over and all the code was working fine. Any suggestions would be helpful

Comment: This? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32038226/error-thread-1-breakpoint-2-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have set the breakpoint by mistake.

Breakpoints are useful for debugging. But if you dont require it, you can do one of the follwing

1) you can hit Cmd + Y and rerun project, this will deactivate your breakpoints but won't delete it.

2) Or you can go to project navigator, and click breakpoint navigator and delete all breakpoints

3) You can also see the blue mark on the left side of your code (main editor), that is a breakpoint itself, you can  click (two finger click) on the blue breakpoint and delete it.