# Print evens app error help - cannot convert to type string

Tags: swift, string, text, label

I've been trying to take a number and display all of the even numbers up to said number in a string. Currently, I think I have everything working but I'm having trouble getting it to display in a label.

The error I'm getting is on: `label.text = factor`.
The error states: "cannot assign value of type '()' to type 'string?'

I was wonder if anyone had any idea how to fix this or improve my code and explain what I did wrong? I'm still kind of new to Swift.

Here's my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var input1 : UITextField!
@IBOutlet var label : UILabel!

@IBAction func factorAction(sender: UIButton) {
    if let text = input1.text {
        if let num = Int(text) {
            // text to int
            let factor = getEvens(<#T##input: Int##Int#>)
            label.text = factor
        } else {
            // Show the user that the entered text isn't a number
        }
    } else {
        // There's no text
    }
}
// notifies user when no text or if a non number string/whole integer has been entered.
// recycled code from factor application because it was useful 

func getEvens(_ input: Int){
    var output: String = ""
    for i in 0 ... input {
        if (i % 2 == 0){
            output += String(i) + ","
        }
    }
    output.remove(at: output.index(before: output.endIndex))
    print(output);
}    // returns result

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

Thanks again guys!

Edit 2: I went ahead and updated the code; currently i'm getting a thread 1: breakpoint 1.1 whenever i try and enter a number into the textbox when testing the app. Any ideas why this would be happening?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var input1 : UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var label : UILabel!

@IBAction func factorAction(sender: UIButton) {
    if let text = input1.text {
        if let num = Int(text) {
            // text to int
            let factor = getEvens(num)
            label.text = factor
        } else {
            // Show the user that the entered text isn't a number
        }
    } else {
        // There's no text
    }
}

// notifies user when no text or if a non number string/whole integer has been entered.
// recycled code from factor application because it was useful

func getEvens(_ input: Int) -> String {
    let output = stride(from: 0, through: input, by: 2)
        .map(String.init)
        .joined(separator: ",")
    return output
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
}
```

Comment: `getEvens(_:)` doesn't return anything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getEvens()` function prints a string to the console, but does not *return* anything. (More precisely, its return type is `Void`
or `()`, and that is where `type '()'` in the error message

> "cannot assign value of type '()' to type 'string?'

comes from.)

What you probably want is

```
func getEvens(_ input: Int) -> String { // <-- Return type is `String`
    var output: String = ""
    for i in 0 ... input {
        if (i % 2 == 0){
            output += String(i) + ","
        }
    }
    output.remove(at: output.index(before: output.endIndex))
    return output // <-- The returned value
}
```

Note that you can achieve the same result with

```
func getEvens(_ input: Int) -> String {
    let output = stride(from: 0, through: input, by: 2)
        .map(String.init)
        .joined(separator: ",")
    return output
}
```

which may be a bit more "Swifty":

- `stride(from: 0, through: input, by: 2)` gives a sequence of
  the even numbers from `0` to `input`,
- `map(String.init)` converts each number to a String, and
- `joined(separator: ",")` concatenates the results to a single
  string, adding a comma between the elements.

Comment: any reason why i'm getting a "Editor placeholder is source file" error next to "let factor = getEvens(Input: Int)" in my code? I'm using the second, shorter code you suggested if that helps

Comment: @cisco21: You have to fill in the actual argument: `let factor = getEvent(num)`.

Comment: getting a thread 1:breakpoint 1.1 whenever i try and enter a number when testing. Updated the post with the code. Thoughts?

Comment: @cisco21: Then you have probably set a breakpoint. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/32038314/1187415.

Comment: thank you so much! you dont know how helpful this has been!