# Why I don't get output from loop on optional dictionary?

Tags: swift, swift3

There is simple example of code, but I don't know why I don't retrieve outputs

```
func printDictOpt (tmp : (Dictionary<String, String>)?) -> (){
for entity in tmp!{
    print("\(entity.key) \(entity.value)")
}
}

var some : [String : String]?
some = [String : String]()

some?["name"] = "Alex"
some?["second"] = "Deeed"

print("count : \(some?.count)")
printDictOpt(tmp: some)
```

Here is output

[image]

Why I don't get `print()`?

**Edit**

```
var some : [String : String]?
some = [String : String]()

some["name"] = "Alex"
some["second"] = "Deeed"

print("count : \(some.count)")
```

If I don't mark some as optional Xcode say that I need to add `?`

```
var some : [String : String]?
some = [String : String]()

some?["name"] = "Alex"
some?["second"] = "Deeed"

print("count : \(some?.count)")
```

Comment: I copied your code into a playground, and I get three lines of output, as expected.

Comment: Maybe you've set a breakpoint without noticing? http://stackoverflow.com/a/32038314/2227743 Looks like execution is stopped after `print("count : \(some?.count)")` and lldb shows up...

Comment: Side question: why are your dictionaries declared optional everywhere? For `some` you don't need optionality, 'cos you init it right in next line, and for func param passing optional will crash app right in first line of code.

Comment: @EricAya yes, it was the reason... I can't think about it... I came from android studio and it works different. Now I understood

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko No problem, I'm glad I could help.

Comment: @EricAya if you add answer I will mark it

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko That's nice of you, thanks, but there's no need, I've marked your question as duplicate of the one I've linked to. :)

Comment: @user28434 I added explanation in question. Did you mean this?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, you don't need to declare anything optional at all, check [this gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/953500fa847ce38bcaabdb2a32c2bec5)

Comment: @user28434 aa, you said about this... I know it, I did it just for practice, I was wondering if I can do it optional